# style startDate and endDate in react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, datepicker, react-datepicker

Please your help is needed. I am working on a project which requires me to only style the startDate and endDate.I am using react-datepicker library. the screenshot of what I want to achieve is down below

Hi Developers, Please your help is needed. I am working on a project which requires me to only style the startDate and endDate.I am using react-datepicker library. the screenshot of what I want to achieve is down below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unr3N.png]

But I am getting this image below
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX1b2]

Below is the DatePicker code

```js
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

function NewMonthCalendar({ confirmDate, cancelMonthDate, startMonthDate, setStartMonthDate, endMonthDate, setEndMonthDate }) {

    const years = range(1990, getYear(new Date()) + 1, 1);

    const onChangeDateHandler = (value) => {
        setStartMonthDate(value[0])
        setEndMonthDate(value[1])
    }

    const ExampleCustomInput = ({ value, onClick }) => (
        <span className="example-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
            {value}
        </span>
    );
    console.log("date",)
    const renderMonthContent = (month, shortMonth, longMonth) => {
        const tooltipText = `Tooltip for month: ${longMonth}`;
        return <span title={tooltipText}>{shortMonth}</span>;
    };

    // const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className='monthCalendar'>
            <DatePicker
                className="custom-input-style"
                renderCustomHeader={({
                    date,
                    changeYear,
                    decreaseYear,
                    increaseYear,
                    prevMonthButtonDisabled,
                    nextMonthButtonDisabled,
                }) => (
                    <div className='monthHeader'>
                        <select
                            className="custom-select-style"
                            value={getYear(date)}
                            onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                                changeYear(value)
                            }
                        >
                            {years.map((option) => (
                                <option key={option} value={option}>
                                    {option}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>

                        <div className='dateArrow'>
                            <button
                                onClick={decreaseYear}
                                disabled={prevMonthButtonDisabled}
                            >
                                <img src={lessthan} alt="" />
                            </button>

                            <button
                                onClick={increaseYear}
                                disabled={nextMonthButtonDisabled}
                            >
                                <img src={greaterthan} alt="" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
                selectsRange={true}
                startDate={startMonthDate}
                endDate={endMonthDate}
                onChange={onChangeDateHandler}
                dateFormat="MMM"
                renderMonthContent={renderMonthContent}
                showMonthYearPicker
                shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
                customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
                inline
            >
                <div className='buttonAction67' >
                    <span onClick={confirmDate}>Confirm</span>
                    <span onClick={cancelMonthDate}>Cancel</span>
                </div>
            </DatePicker>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

antDesign library use: Try this code...

```
import React from 'react';

import { DatePicker} from 'antd';

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';
const App: React.FC = () => (

<RangePicker
      defaultValue={[dayjs('2015/01/01', dateFormat), dayjs('2015/01/01', dateFormat)]}
      format={dateFormat}
    />

)
```